# Flame camera.moveTo - render objects off the game canvas

Tags: flame, forge2d

When moving the camera, the BodyComponents gets rendered off the game area, do you know why or is it a bug?

[image]

Flutter:

```
child: Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        const Text("data"),
        Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 300,
            height: 600,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                GameWidget<BallsSampleForge2DGame>(
                    game: BallsSampleForge2DGame(),
```

Flame:

```
camera.moveTo(<some vector>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GameWidget` is not clipped by default.
You can either use a `FixedResolutionViewport` which automatically clips the canvas, or you can wrap the `GameWidget` in Flutter's `ClipRect` widget.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRect-class.html

Comment: Good one - thanks!